# Pretest-posttest plus control design

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, effect-size

I am evaluating *the effect of an intervention (treatment: a lecture) on the ability to spot behavioral clues of emotions using visual stimuli* using **pretest-posttest plus control group** experimental design.

The experimental group is given the first set of stimuli, then there is intervention and the second set of stimuli follows. Naturally, the same without the intervention occurs in the case of the control group. **Two groups, two measurements each.**

**1. How to determine the number of subjects needed in each group?**
(Ideally using **G*Power 3** – my problem is that I literally do not understand which method should I pick [I guess ANOVA: Repeated measures, between factors] and on what basis are the desired **power** and **effect size** determined.)

Suppose that I have got data from 30 experimental and 20 control subjects. The most appropriate method to use seems to be the **rANOVA** (*GLM -> Repeated Measures* in SPSS).

Data example:

```
    group    pre    post
1     exp     10      15
2     exp      8       9
3     con      8       7
4     con      5       6
```

**2. How to perform the same analysis in R?**

**3. After the analysis, which data are best to describe the significance of the intervention?**

Apparently, I am a total newbie and indeed a confused one because for the last two days, I have been searching and found many contradictory claims, suggesting **two paired t-tests** or **Mann-Whitney U**, without discussing the procedure of choosing appropriately sized groups in a practical way.

Thanks for any help, improving suggestions are welcome.

Comment: With regard to determining power & effect size: you want a good chance of estimating an effect of an interesting size, given the errors.  A 'good chance' is relative to the bother & expense of doing the experiment. 'Interesting' is for *you* to decide, not a statistician.  You also need to estimate the error variance; if you've really no idea a pilot study would be advisable (as it often is anyway).